# Converting binary to ASCII

Tags: c++

I have a text full of binary values(0-1) and i'm trying to convert it to ASCII , I made a code but it didn't work well and it takes too long time and writing, this is a part of it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("C:\\test.txt",ios :: binary);
    ifstream file("E:\\mnmn.txt");
    string content;
    while(file >> content)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
        {
            while((content[i] == '0') 
                    && (content[i+1] == '0')
                    && (content[i+2] == '0')
                    && (content[i+3] == '0')
                    && (content[i+4] == '0')
                    && (content[i+5] == '0')
                    && (content[i+6] == '0')
                    && (content[i+7] == '0')
            {
                char *data = "00000000";
                char c = strtol(data, 0, 2);
                fout<<c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have to do the same for all values and even if i did the program repeats the values because the zeros and ones is connected without any spaces between , isn't there a better way to convert it?

the text contains:

```
00001111101010001001010101110
```

etc..

Comment: The "binary" file, is it the *characters* `'0'` and `'1'`? Then it's not really a binary file, it's a text file.

Comment: You should really use `string::compare` to compare to "00000000" instead of doing a character by character comparison like that. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: Also, if you read a string from the input file containing only the characters `'1'` and `'0'`, then you can use that string directly in your call to `strtol` (or [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)).

Comment: binary value ,not binary file.

Comment: Then why are you opening the files in binary mode?

Comment: @Cyber i didn't get your point i'm sorry, how would i use compare in this situation?

Comment: Show the contents of `mnmn.txt`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry my mistake i'll edit it,please if you can ,make an example for what you suggested i'm kinda new to c++

Comment: @user3516293 I mean instead of that huge `while` block, you can just say `while (content.compare("00000000") != 0)` and that is the same as the code you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC 4.8.2: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 read-01.cpp

```
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream fout("test.txt");
  std::ifstream fin("mnmn.txt");
  char ic;
  std::bitset<8> oc;
  int i = 8;

  while (fin >> ic) {
    oc[--i] = ic - '0';

    if (0 == i) {
      fout << static_cast<char>(oc.to_ulong());
      i = 8; } }

  return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the contents of the file character by character and accumulate the characters in a variable. After reading 8 characters, you have the ASCII value. The core of your function can be changed to:

```
int inChar = 0;
int outChar = 0;
int count = 0;;
while( (inChar = file.get()) != EOF )
{
   int x = inChar - '0';

   // Ignore newlines and other characters that are not '0' or '1'.
   if ( x == 0 || x == 1 )
   {
      // Accumulate the bit into the output char.
      outChar = (outChar << 1) + x;
      ++count;
      if ( count == 8 )
      {
         fout.put(outChar);
         outChar = 0;
         count = 0;
      }
   }
}

// Deal with unused outChar.
if ( count > 0 )
{
   cout << "There are " << count << " bits that were not used.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get eight characters (bits) at a time from the input you read, then you should use the [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function, and you can use the resulting string directly, either in `std::stoi` (or if you don't have it `std::strtol`).

Something like

```
while (file >> content)
{
    do
    {
        std::string byte = content.substr(0, 8);  // Get eight "bits"

        fout << std::stoi(byte, nullptr, 2);  // Convert and output to file

        content = content.substr(8);  // The remaining bits
    } while (!content.empty());
}
```

Comment: Dev c++ couldn't identify stoi or nullptr ?

Comment: @user3516293 Then use `strtol` and `0`. Or add the `-std=c++11` compiler flag.